# php compare dates without year

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to compare two dates. I've found many threads to this topic, but in every thread there was also a year. What I want to achieve is compare the dates without any year value. Example:

```
if(31.07 > 16.11) {
    // do stuff
}
```

I tried the following:

```
$sDayMonth = date("d.m", strtotime($row["date"]));
$sDateCompare = date("d.m", strtotime("31.07"));

if($sDayMonth > $sDateCompare){
    // do stuff
}
```

Unfortunately it always executes the code in the if statement. I cannot figure out why. Is this even possible? If yes, what am I doing wrong?

The variable `$row` is a row returned from SQL database, it contains the correct value.

Comment: Fundamentally, the logic is flawed in that there is no way to establish whether one date falls before or after another unless you add a year. If you always assume "this year", add it to the code, and just compare "strtotime($row['date'] . '.2016') > strtotime('31.07.2016')". But that's quite ugly too.

Comment: Why "d.m" ? "md" could be better

Comment: @markdwhite Well, it's not always the same year. I have to check in which season the date is. E.g. 16.11.2013 is in season "2013/2014" and 04.02.2014 is also in season "2013/2014", but there are two different years. The season break is on 31.07 in every year. You know what I mean? :)

Comment: @Mate Oh, didn't thought about this. But unfortunately it has the same effect. If statement is always executed :/

Comment: Are you just trying to figure out if a date is after April 31st?

Comment: @Mate yes, but I just noticed that `$sDateCompare` is always "0101" instead of "0731"

Comment: @LoganBailey Yes, if a date is after July 31st, it has to execute the code, otherwise ignore the code in the if statement...

Comment: @Tyler I do see what you mean, which would suggest that your approach is flawed. Unless you have the year stored in the DB too, in which case you can use that and still directly compare using strtotime(). Though the DateTime object is the better way to compare dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just pick a constant year which will be used in both dates you're comparing. This way you can still make use of strtotime().

```
$year = '2000';
$ts1 = strtotime($row["date"] . '.' . $year);
$ts2 = strtotime("31.07." . $year);

if($ts1 > $ts2){
     // do stuff
}
```

Alternatively, you can concatenate $month and $day in this order. That way you're able to convert these to integer and compare them this way, eg. Aug 11 would be 811 and Nov 30 is 1130 and 1130 > 811.