# check if date is between two dates without year

Tags: php

I have this script for checking if today is between two dates.

```
<?php

$now = new DateTime();
$startdate = new DateTime("2021-12-06");
$enddate = new DateTime("2021-12-27");

if($startdate <= $now && $now <= $enddate) {
  echo "christmas time";
}else{
  echo "No christmas time";
}
```

How can I check this without the year ?
I want to use the script next year also without changing the year.

Comment: @HenkieForward Great.. So the technique could be the same. Just remove `2021` and attach whatever current year you get from `date('Y')`

Comment: @nice_dev $startdate = new DateTime("'date('Y')'-12-06"); this way ?

Comment: Checkout these: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35236103/5468463, https://stackoverflow.com/q/37607512/5468463, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12230738/5468463, etc

Comment: @HenkieForward Like `$startdate = new DateTime(date('Y') . '-12-06');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only wish to compare on the `m` and `d` annually, so only create a string to compare against that consists of `m-d`.  Then you can shorten your start and end dates to only be `m-d` as well.  Because you have formatted your dates from bigger unit to smaller unit (month then day), you can simply compare the dates as regular strings.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/lAmqq))

```
$now = date('m-d');
$start_md = "12-06";
$end_md = "12-27";

if ($start_md <= $now && $now <= $end_md) {
  echo "Christmas time";
} else {
  echo "Not christmas time";
}
```

Comment: I created this script in a function now. checkDatum. Thats working, but how i include this? $datum = opendir('./".checkDatum()."/'); The function returns only text hello, but in opendir i need to / it before and after.

Comment: I have no idea what you new requirement is -- I recommend that you ask a new, clear question.

Comment: 3v4l.org/d6rNc this i mean

Comment: @Hen https://3v4l.org/aqtZZ

Comment: @mickmackusa Good answer, but I don't think this would work if you were trying to figure out if something was between 12-06 and 1-06 though.

Comment: This question is specifically checking within the scope of a single year -- which is why they've asked for a year-less comparison.  My answer also explicitly states `You only wish to compare on the m and d annually, so only create a string to compare against that consists of m-d.`